# How can I determine the correct /dev/input/event* name to monitor or at least fix it to something pre-known?

Tags: ubuntu, events, touch, raspbian

I am running Raspbian Lite on a Raspberry Pi Zero. It has a touch sensitive LCD display. I have a (perl) program that reads touch events from /dev/input/event* and responds appropriately.

The problem I have is that the event file name sometimes flips between /dev/input/event0 and event1 after a reboot. Both files always exist.

Why does it do that? What sets the filename that is used?

Is there any way that I can detect which file is "active"? (There are no events on the other filename as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 1):

Look for the presence of a directory named /dev/input/by-path or /dev/input/by-id.  Inside these directories there will be links to your hardware that will persist across boot cycles.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will do it. I'll change my software and wait and see what happens after future reboots.

Answer (score 0):

The `N` in `eventN` is assigned chronologically by the kernel and is therefore non-deterministic. It's not a reliable way to read from a specific device, even if it appears to always be the same, if for example a newer kernel changes the loading order. Always use `/dev/input/by-path` or `/dev/input/by-id` when available.

However you may notice that not all `eventN` files have a corresponding entry in `/dev/input/by-path` or `/dev/input/by-id`. For example, you might not be able to find a symlink for your power button. In such cases, there is also the file `/proc/bus/input/devices`, in which you can find an entry for every input device. And in the `Handlers=` line you should be able to find `eventN`, corresponding to `/dev/input/eventN`. It seems like there an entry for every `/dev/input/eventN`, at least in my testing.